# Rails - how to return just text of an ActiveRecord record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model of cities and one of the attributes is the city 'name'.

I've done a helper method to return 'n' number of cities and the implementation is below:

helper method:

```
def list_cities(start, stop)
    cities = City.find(:all, order: "name asc", limit: stop-start, select: "name")
    cities.each do |city|
        "<li> #{city.name} </li>"
    end
end
```

view code:

```
   <%= list_cities(1,22) %>
```

However, it returns the following in the view:

```
 [#<City name: "Abilene">]
```

How do I get just the text of the city name and get rid of the rest of the query?

Comment: It sound like you are looking for pluck: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your method list_cities does not return the string you think it does. It just returns an array of city objects because that's what the method each does. It looks like you're mixing controller and view logic into a helper. What I'd do is:

Set a @cities instance variable in the controller:

```
@cities = City.find(:all, order: "name asc", limit: stop-start, select: "name")
```

In the view:

```
<% @cities.each do |city| %>
  <li><%= city.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

This way you keep your controller and view logic separated.

Comment: Ok, that worked for me. But I guess a follow-up question is, if this type of logic is not supposed to be placed in a helper, what is the ideal use of helper methods?

Answer (score 1):

What Erez answered is the best way to approach this issue.  But I'd like to share what you can do to your method to achieve what you want with minimal changes.  You need to change your helper to the following

```
def list_cities(start, stop)
  cities = City.all(order: 'name ASC', limit: stop - start, select: 'name')
  cities.map { |city| "<li> #{city.name} </li>" }.join.html_safe
end
```

The other changes are just small refactors to reduce code.  Without knowing the rails version you're using, I didn't change the query but if you're using 3.2, you should have access to `pluck` which is faster since it won't create ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: I do have access to pluck. Would the query then be: City.all(order: 'name ASC', limit: stop-start).pluck(:name)?

Comment: nope. It should be chained like `City.order('name ASC').limit(stop - start).pluck(:name)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
def list_cities(start, stop)
  content = ''
  cities = City.find(:all, order: "name asc", limit: stop-start, select: "name")
  cities.each do |city|
    content << "<li> #{city.name} </li>\n"
  end
  content
end
```